# What is the use of tape-B in celeste game?

Tags: celeste

I am wondering, what is the use of tape-B mode? It seems all the same with the original mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The B tapes are additional areas in the game. You can clear them in each chapter for achievements.

Comment: So just achievements, no other use, right?

Comment: Yeah, achievements and more levels. You won't unlock a new skill or anything like that.

Comment: No new skills, but you do collect more crystal hearts from B sides, which are required to progress in Chapter 9.